# nginx & php-fpm very slow on first access

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I have a nginx 1.4.5 webserver with php-fpm 5.5.7 running on my server, but if my server stays idle for a while, accessing it is very slow. It takes about 10-20 seconds to get the response (first byte), after that its fast again.
I dont know why it takes ages to respond on first access after a while. I tried both unix sockets and tcp, no effect. Heres my config:

NGINX:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1000;
    multi_accept on;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65s;
    keepalive_requests 1000;
    gzip off;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

my php standard config:

```
include=etc/fpm.d/*.conf
[global]
error_log = log/php-fpm.log
log_level = notice
emergency_restart_threshold = 10
emergency_restart_interval = 1m
process_control_timeout = 10s
```

now the pool which takes ages to respond (first byte):

```
[myweb]
;listen = /usr/local/etc/sockets/myweb.socket
listen = 127.0.0.1:9001
listen.owner = max
listen.group = max
listen.mode = 0666
user = max
group = max
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.status_path = /status
pm.min_spare_servers = 2
pm.max_spare_servers = 4
pm.max_requests = 200
slowlog = /home/max/logs/max.slow.log
pm.status_path = /status
request_terminate_timeout = 120s
rlimit_files = 131072
rlimit_core = unlimited
catch_workers_output = yes
php_admin_value[default_charset] = UTF-8
php_value[error_reporting] = 2147483647
php_admin_flag[display_errors] = On
php_admin_flag[display_startup_errors] = On
php_admin_value[error_log] = "/var/tmp/php.max.error.log"
php_admin_value[log_level] = DEBUG
php_admin_value[upload_max_filesize] = 10M
php_admin_value[post_max_size] = 10M
php_admin_value[max_execution_time] = 60
```

**Server tech details:**

```
AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 3400+
4GB RAM
500 GB RAID1 HDD
website runs on MySQL 5.5.35
nginx 1.4.5
php-fpm 5.5.7
```

**Timeline pic**
The browser waited 22 seconds for first byte. Receiving the content took only 86ms.
So this must be the server (nginx/php-fpm):
[image]

The website runs in a users home folder, the user is max. Everything works fine. No slow log files generated, no php errors, no nginx errors.

Why in the world its slow on first byte?

**UPDATE 2:**

Setting nginx's error log to DEBUG, gave me only some infos about the match.
But right after i called the url, i got 3 log entries printed while watching it with "tail -f", so nginx is doing its right as usual, right after its redirecting to the php script, it takes about 15-20 seconds before i get my response and more logs printed. so either its php-fpm, or mysql.
I would like to know how can i "reset" my server so i can easily reproduce that long first-byte response. I guess its caching the result or something and using it after the first call, how to kill that cache so i can test. Because i can test this only once in 3 or 4 hours, then i have to wait before i can try again getting the slow first-byte response.

Comment: Describe the server on which this is running.

Comment: Is there a DNS resolution involved ? Can you show us a firebug loading timeline ?

Comment: added server tech details, unfortunately as it has been requested now, it runs normal again. have to wait and retry after a few hours to check the loading timeline from firebug.

Comment: Already tried to increase log verbosity to info level? (Even debug if supported)

Comment: setting it to debug, gives me only info about my location matches and how it redirects, looks fine. then i see some "closed keepalive connection". nothing i should worry about or?

Comment: Do you have the problem if you connect directly instead of going through that proxy?

Comment: This isn't your problem, but a quick suggestion. You should have at least 2 worker processes due to how nginx splits workload among workers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Darn, it was the CMS itself, not my code running on the CMS. I'm using Contenido (an easy to use CMS) but it has something called "PseudoCron-Jobs" and there are plenty of them being executed after a while. Most of them i don't need, so i disabled them. Now its fast.

So whoever wants to use Contenido, check the contenido/cronjobs folder and disable some in the crontab.txt file to skip the stuff you actually don't need.

NGinx 1.4.5 with PHP-FPM 5.5.7 and MySQL 5.5 runs fine so far. :-)